# RSS feed with full questions?

Tags: feature-request, feed

Is there an RSS feed of all questions (or some subset like "questions that have been marked answered") that contains in each [item]

1. the full text of the question
2. the highest voted answer

This RSS feed could function (particularly well on certain SO sites such as English) as a way of quickly acquiring tiny bits of uncommon knowledge.

Comment: It would also be really useful to set up a competing site :)

Comment: I think you can build something like this using the API.

Comment: Try [this tool](http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com).